# nested Parallel.For Loop - Cancellation.Token doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task, cancellation

I have the following problem: I have a tight loop (on purpose) which starts on a click event in the MainWindow.cs of my WPF application.

Now, a stop event triggered by another button should stop the tight loop and end the Task.

In my tight loop I have a `Parallel.For` loop.The idea is that I have to do a certain amount of things simultaneously (Parallel.For) and this over and over again (tight loop). I don't know if this is the best approach but it's the only one that I had, however it works :) .

I have a problem with the Cancellation.Token which doesn’t seem to do anything.
How do I stop the loop and end the Task correctly.

Here’s my code:

```
var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;

Task dlTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( 
() =>
{
  do
  {
    Parallel.For(0, num, po, i => {
      if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        // do work
      }
    });
  }
  while (!token.IsCancellationRequested);

}, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

dlTask.ContinueWith(prev => 
{
     //clean up
}, uiScheduler);
```

I tried it with `po.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` and without and it didn't stop.

```
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (cts.IsCancellationRequested || po.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    cts.Cancel();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE: Solution thanks to  Damien_The_Unbeliever**:

```
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  cts.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: Please use tags instead of putting things like " (C#)" in your subject line.

Comment: Sorry, I also added it in my tags

Answer (score 2):

You need to call **cts.Cancel()** in the event handler for your stop button.  This will tell your cancelation token that you have requested cancellation.

Comment: Thank you .. I forgot to add code as well. Have a look. I think I did what you suggested

Comment: @user774326 - your conditionals inside the `btnStop_Click` method mean that you'll only call `Cancel` if cancellation has already been requested...

Comment: Yipee ... now it works thank you ... One more thing how do I restart the Tasks !?!

That means if the user clicks start again the whole process should start all over again. Is there a reset cancellation Token Request to false type of thing??